# encontrar referencia em outra tabela

Tags: mysql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

1. cadastro
2. lotes

Onde a `cadastro` contém a chave primaria `id_cadastro` que
nos `lotes` faz referência a ela.

Porém, o banco não era normalizado, então a chave estrangeira que faz referência a `id_cadastro` não existe.

Estou fazendo o cadastro manualmente, mas é quase impossível localizar todas as referências que não existem.

Existe alguma maneira que eu possa fazer a busca de referências inexistentes de forma automática com comandos SQL?

Comment: Coloque a estrutura completa das tabelas

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que isso deve resolver

```
select * from lotes where lotes.id_cadastro not in (select id_cadastro from cadastro)
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem duas formas de se fazer isso, a primeira é essa aqui:

```
SELECT * FROM lotes a
WHERE a.id_cadastro NOT IN (
    SELECT id_cadastro FROM cadastro
);
```

e a segunda é essa:

```
SELECT * FROM lotes a
LEFT JOIN cadastro b ON a.id_cadastro = b.id_cadastro
WHERE b.id_cadastro IS NULL;
```

A `segunda opção` tem um ganho enorme de performance sobre a `primeira opção`.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver com o seguinte código

```
    SELECT  *
FROM    lotes l
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  null 
        FROM    cadastro c
        WHERE    c.id_cadastro = l.id_cadastro
        )
```